# Ubuntu equivalent to windows cmd command

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

I was just wondering if anyone knows the Linux equivalent to the " prompt" and "title" command in cmd. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title` in cmd seems to be a command for changing title of terminal, in bash, you can do this:

```
echo -ne "\033]0;The Message You Want\007"
```

terminal under linux do not have the command `prompt`, but you can set `PS1` variable:

```
PS1="the prompt you want"
```

For the variables which can be used in PS1, you can try

```
man bash
```

and search for the `prompting` section